# Transferring from Visa 600 to 804 Aged Parent? | Bridging?

Tags: visa, australia

A person is coming to Australia on a tourist visa 600. Then applies onshore for an aged parent visa 804. Some websites say that the application generated a bridging visa that will allow the person to stay in Australia while 804 is being processed. How does that work?

Comment: Some posts here https://www.pomsinoz.com/topic/212165-aged-parent-visa-804/ indicating that it can take years if not decades to move onto 804 status. The official site says that new Parent and Aged Parent visa applications lodged that meet the criteria to be queued are likely to take at least 30 years for final processing.​ https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-processing-times/family-visa-processing-priorities/parent-visas-queue-release-dates

Comment: Have you looked at all the information available on https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-finder/join-family? Do you have a specific question or problem you need help with on the topic?  ‘How does that work’ is quite broad, what do you want to know that isn’t already explained on the official website?

Comment: If a person is coming to Australia on a 600 with the intention of applying for an 804 then it seems they are not a genuine visitor. Also, a 600 visa may come with a 'No further stay' requirement.